# Configure Hyperlink using calculated field to display in "Datasheet View"

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, datasheet, sharepoint-fields

We have a requirement to show hyperlink (URL underlying a text) in Datasheet view.

**Approach 1**: We tried to create a hyperlink field and configured a WF to concatenate the URLs. It is working fine except all users are getting “Resolve Conflict” errors if they try to make changes for second time.

[image: Error with Workflow]

Approach 2: We tried to create a calculated column and concatenating the URL to form with desired query strings. But it is displaying as text and not a link. PFB screenshot for reference:
[image: Problem with calculated field]

Please share us your suggestions to display hyperlink in Datasheet view.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution for this. we created a workflow and configured the content type to trigger this workflow at the end of each day using retention policies.

That way, WF won't be triggered everytime user navigates through the list items.